# A difficult integral (Elliptic Kida vortex)

Tags: integration

I love integrating, and I am trying to become better at it. 
For those of you who like a challenge (I suppose), see below.
$$\frac{d r}{d \theta} = -\frac{r^2+1}{r^2-1} \frac{\tan{2 \theta}}{2 r} + \frac{\omega}{2 e} \frac{1}{(r+1)^2} \frac{1}{\cos{2  \theta}} + \frac{\gamma}{2 e r \cos{2 \theta}},$$
where $\omega$, $e$, and $\gamma$ are positive real constants. This differential equation is encountered in the article "Motion of an Elliptic Vortex in a Uniform Shear Flow" by Kida, and the solution is given by 
$$ \sin{2 \theta} = \frac{\omega}{e} \Big( \frac{r}{r^2-1} \ln{\Big[\frac{(r+1)^2}{4 s r}}\Big] + \frac{\gamma}{\omega} \frac{r-1}{r+1} \Big), $$
where $s(>0)$ is a constant of integration. Any idea on how to derive this, or is this one of those cases meant for Mathematica?